# Why might diffForHumans be ignored in the Laravel5.5 model accessor?

Tags: php, laravel-5, timestamp

I want to define an accessor for the created_at field. My code is:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
    return $value->diffForHumans();
}
```

It throws an `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null` error.

But `$task->created_at->diffForHumans();` works fine in the view.

Comment: when I fill that its show me `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string`

Comment: please show more of your code .. like the model/controller having the $task and model/controller you want to add greCreateAtAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use 'Carbon' class and create a Accessor method and follow the following code.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
        {
            $carbonDate = new Carbon($value);
            return $carbonDate->diffForHumans();
        }
```

or

```
$datetime = Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 8, 25); // or 
$datetime of course
return $datetime->diffForHumans();
```